# can you get freckles in animal crossing welcome amiibo?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

My friend got a tan recently in acnl because she visits the island very often. But I was wondering - can you get freckles?

Answer (score 1):

No. However in New Horizons you can wear a custom design on your face, so you can have freckles in New Horizons.